# Handling word index in text files

Tags: python

> wordlist A: book jesus christ son david son abraham jacob judah his brothers perez amminadab
>
> wordlist B: akwụkwọ jizọs kraịst nwa devid nwa ebreham jekọb juda ya ụmụnne pirez aminadab
>
> #### file.txt A:
>
> 1. the book of the history of jesus christ , son of david , son of abraham :
> 2. abraham became father to isaac ; isaac became father to jacob ; jacob became father to judah and his brothers ;
>
> #### file.txt B:
>
> 1. akwụkwọ nke kọrọ akụkọ banyere jizọs kraịst , nwa devid , nwa ebreham :
> 2. ebreham mụrụ aịzik ; aịzik amụọ jekọb ; jekọb amụọ juda na ụmụnne ya ndị ikom ;

I have 2 above word-lists (say A & B) of 2 diff. languages. Both contain word translation of each other in order. My task is to run these word-lists through 2 separate files.txt of both languages like word-list A through file.txt A and vice versa, then return a line for both txt files, each will contain the index numbers of both word-list where they were found on each line of the txt paired like:

> 1. 2:1 7:6 8:7 10:9 12:10 14:12 16:13 [ 2:1 = 2 index of book in txt.file A and 1-akwụkwọ in txt.file B and so on]
> 2. 1:1 11:6 13:8 17:10 19:12 20:13 [ 1:1 = 1 index of abraham in txt.file A and 1- ebreham in txt.file B and so on].
>      see codes below:

```
import sys

def wordlist(filename):
    wordlist = []
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            wordlist.append(line)
    return wordlist

eng = []
for lines in open('eng_try.txt', 'rb'):
    line = lines.strip()
    eng.append(line)
igb = []
for lines in open('igb_try.txt', 'rb'):
    line = lines.strip()
    igb.append(line)

i = 0
while i < len(eng):
    eng_igb_verse_pair = eng[i] + " " + igb[i]
    line = eng_igb_verse_pair.strip().split()
    for n in range(0, len(wordlist('eng_wordlist.txt'))):
        eng_word =  wordlist('eng_wordlist.txt').pop(n)
        igb_word =  wordlist('igb_wordlist.txt').pop(n)
        if eng_word in line and igb_word in line:
            print '{0} {1}:{2}'.format(i, line.index[eng_word], line.index[igb_word])
    i += 1
```

This actually prints empty. I know my problem is in the last segment of the program. Can someone help. I am not that experienced python programmer. Apologies if I didn't construct my explanation well.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
import sys

def checkLine(line_eng, line_igb):
  eng_words = line_eng.split()
  igb_words = line_igb.split()
  for word in eng_words:
    if word in eng:
      igb_word = igb[eng.index(word)]
      print "%d:%d" % ( eng_words.index(word)+1, igb_words.index(igb_word)+1),

def linelist(filename):
    lineslist = []
    for line in open(filename, 'rb'):
      lineslist.append(line)
    return lineslist

eng = []
for lines in open('eng_try.txt', 'rb'):
    line = lines.strip()
    for w in line.split():
      eng.append(w)
igb = []
for lines in open('igb_try.txt', 'rb'):
    line = lines.strip()
    for w in line.split():
      igb.append(w)

eng_lines = linelist("eng_wordlist.txt")
igb_lines = linelist("igb_wordlist.txt")

for n in range(0, len(eng_lines)):
  print "%d. " % (n+1),
  checkLine(eng_lines[n],igb_lines[n])
  print
```

For your files i got result:

```
1. 2:1 7:6 8:7 10:9 12:10 10:9 16:13
2. 1:1 11:7 11:7 17:11 19:14 20:13
```

BR
Parasit Hendersson

Comment: Thanks parasit but I got this error on this line: print "%d:%d" % ( eng_words.index(word)+1, igb_words.index(igb_word)+1),
ValueError: 'nke' is not in list. been trying to know if I could fix it.

Comment: Also I forgot to say that line nos are not serially. it depends on the line no of either txt files, file.txt A or B because both have aligned line nos. Like the next line in both after two is 4 not 3, next might be 7. so it depends on the line nos in any of the text files. Thanks.